# How can I reconcile my philosophy with my faith?

Tags: free-will, christianity

My philosophy holds the belief that freedom is one of the most important traits, and that when given the choice, without manipulation, a person will choose to do the right thing. Furthermore, that the hope that there will eventually be a world without laws, but in spite of this, people will choose to do the right thing simply because it's right. This is something that is good, and something I think that God wants of us. But here are some problems regarding it.

The essence of what a law really is at the end of a day, is basically something that says that if you do this you'll be punished. The reason why its there is to prevent people from doing that action. Yet the truest way to see the true character of a person is to give them freedom to do whatever they wish without any punishment of whatever they do, good or evil. If they choose to do good, then they are good. If they choose to do evil, then they are evil. But how do you magnify that on a huge world scale? If a person commits evil, then obviously people are going to punish them or deal with them one way or another which would be the same thing as having a law there against evil, the only difference here that there are no laws.

In addition to this, why did God make a rule in the Garden of Eden? Why didn't He just say to Adam and Eve that eating from the Tree was wrong, but they will have the freedom to choose whether or not they can eat from it? Why did he explicitly make a rule saying that they cannot eat from it? Any sort of rules or laws psychologically limits freedom. The ONLY way you can see a person's true nature is giving them freedom that unlimited by anything. But that would mean no punishment evil. What do you think?

Comment: This post seems better fitted for the http://christianity.stackexchange.com/ or for the http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: A similar question was closed today on C.SE, and it wouldn't work well on BH.SE either.

Comment: Why was the question closed? It seems to me it would be best answered by a philosopher or someone knowledgeable about Christianity. It asks about a moral system and specifically the Christian one. However it doesn't seem to ask just one question except, perhaps, "What do you think?"
Perhaps @user5277222 could add what they think is the core of their problem.

Comment: This question shouldn't be closed, but the questioner should ask specific questions about free will. Can we have criminal punishment without free will? What theories exist about free will and what are their implications for criminal punishment and for individual progress toward being a better person? Something like that.

Comment: Your philosophy essentially amounts to the hope that man may eventually be glorified for his ability to do good. That's clearly not based on the Bible, so why would you suppose it to be true?

Comment: You might wikipedia the concept of "mens rea": if you don't know that something is wrong, and you do it, is it really immoral/wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that some alternatives may result in bad consequences or punishment does not limit free will. This is shown by the fact that humans often make the choice that they know will result in bad consequences. In your reference to the Garden of Eden, if Adam and Eve did not have free will, they would have been unable to disobey God and thus would never have eaten the forbidden fruit.

What you appear to be getting at is that bad consequences can discourage people from exercising their free will in certain ways. This is true, but it doesn't refute the existence of free will. You can also rightly claim that if an authority imposes punishment for certain actions, they are influencing people's exercise of free will, but does not eliminate free will.

Regarding your religious beliefs, since this is a philosophy forum, I will limit what I say here to this. The Christian teaching of free will refers to the human capability to choose right or wrong, but it doesn't imply that people should be able to choose wrong without consequences. Indeed, it states the contrary. Now if you are saying that your philosophy values unrestricted freedom without punishment, you would be right in saying that it conflicts with orthodox Christianity.